# "They had to move the interview to the new year." What does "the new year" mean here?

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-in-context

When people say "They had to move the interview to the new year.", does that mean the interview will take place in January next year (or even January 1st), or just anytime next year?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Used in this kind of context, "new year" idiomatically means a short time into the next calendar year. It isn't a specific date and it doesn't have to be January, but it tends to only be used this way for short postponements that move something from late in one year to early in the next. For example, if something was scheduled for December 2021 and it was moved to February 2022, it might be said that it has been "postponed until the new year".

Saying that something is now taking place "*next* year" could sound like it has been postponed a whole 12 months, so this is a way of countering that. It also seems to be a way of accounting for the end-of-year holidays which may add to the postponement of something. So whereas you might normally put something off until "next week" or "next month", the holidays at the end of December may push something postponed into the following calendar year.

Comment: in some contexts, it might refer to the financial or tax year, or the academic year rather than the calendar year

Comment: @Tristan You don't need the word 'new' for that to be the case. A 'year' could mean a calendar year, a financial year, an academic year... but "new year" is more often than not referring to the calendar. I would always be specific if I meant "the new financial year", for example.

Comment: financial year would usually be specified, but academic years are often just referred to as the new year

Comment: On the other hand, a comment that says "on the New Year" (particularly if capitalised like that) refers specifically to January the 1st.

Comment: "on the New Year" doesn't sound natural to my (American) ear, compared to "on New Year's Day".

Comment: Considering `i` and `o` are neighbours on a qwerty keyboard, I would assume "on the New Year" to be a typo and read it as "in the New Year".

Comment: @Tristan American academics wouldn't use "in the new year" to refer to academic years. I don't know about financial or tax years.

Comment: @AzorAhai-him- at UK universities (or at least mine) it's common, although I think "in the next year" would probably be more common

Comment: @chepner I'm with you about the "on the New Year", but I find the posters phrase "to the new year" very unnatural too. I would use "past New Year" or just "to January" or "to February" instead. (March and further would just be "to next year" to me. Too far away to be more specific.)

Answer (score 2):

It probably means early next calendar year - i.e. January.
To possibly offer a little more context, and venturing outside the scope of this thread, this often happens if the budget for a position has expired part way through the year, but a new annual budget may fund the position in the new year.